# Can I retrieve higher resolution map tiles?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I couldn't quite find anything current that relates to this question, so I wanted to ask...

If you go to Google Maps (via maps.google.com), so long as your location is on, it will set you by default at zoom level 15. Now, on Google Maps API, you can specify zoom just fine - it's the scrolling steps that are different. Whereas in the API, you can only step by +/- 1, the motherbase Google Map however, steps +/- .01 -- decimal places!

To test this out myself (I never thought to try it before), I threw in some decimals to my zoom level, and it works! But it is really... Blurry.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
 center: {
  lat: 38.8563801,
  lng: -88.3202496
 },
 zoom: 9.27,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

It's apparent that the API *might* only serve tiles by those specific zoom levels, but is it possible to get high quality map tiles with decimal stepping, as the main Google Map does?

**EDIT:**

API

[image: API is blurry at .27]

Google's

[image: Google's is crisp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first posted this as a comment but thought I'd develop a bit more.

I had never tried a non-integer zoom level as the documentation says:

> Valid values: Integers between zero, and up to the supported [maximum zoom level](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom)

for the zoom property, and I never saw any documented way of achieving this.

There is [this feature request though](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828923), to which you can subscribe. But don't expect this to happen any time soon...

Intersting thing is

```
map.setZoom(1.5);
map.getZoom(); // Outputs 1.5
```

So I thought, maybe you can use this with your own imagery, but...

```
var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {

        console.log(zoom); // Outputs 1
    }
});
```

So that doesn't work. In other words, I suppose you are stuck with integers for now.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for looking into it! I noticed some inconsistency with `ImageMapType` zoom level as well, I wonder if the `setZoom` and `getZoom` working with non-integers is leftovers from experimenting on Google's side. What about trying to store the `getZoom` and using that `var` instead of the getTileUrl parameter, I wonder? I'll keep thinking. Not super important, but I know it'd make the designers very happy at work...

Comment: Might be worth trying indeed. Glad it helped anyway.